# After I added the association table nothing is committed into the database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building an app for rating beers at an event. The beers one can rate should be added to a table, as well should the event be added to another table and the beers and the event should be connected. Since at an event there is more than just one beer to be tasted and a beer can be tasted at multiple events, I want to make a m:n-relationship. I'm doing this with python3, I'm using flask and flasksqlalchemy. I'm using an sqlite-database.

The model I builded sofar looks like this:

```
#association table
event_beer = db.Table('event_beer',
                      db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'), primary_key=True),
                      db.Column('beer_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('beer.id'), primary_key=True))

class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{name}'

class Beer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'beer'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    event = db.relationship('Event', secondary=event_beer)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.event}'
```

I omitted a few Columns which don't have any Foreign Keys or so for the sake of simplicity. The code which is executed when I want to save the recorded data is:

```
event = Event(name = 'event_name')
beer1 = Beer(name = 'beerone')
beer2 = Beer(name = 'beertwo')
beer1.event.append(event)
beer2.event.append(event)
db.session.commit()
```

The values to be saved aren't strings, but for the sake of simplicity I replaced them. The values are there though and in the database there aren't any empty rows.

I don't know whether I set up the model wrong or whether it's an issue while committing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm deeply sorry, I just found the problem. Obviously I forgot to **add the items to the session**. All that missed were `db.session.add(event)`. I was trying to figure this out for at least 6 hours now but I just found it after I posted the problem to stackoverflow.